# selenium firefoxdriver - wait for ajax

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

When testing an ajax page there is a challenge how to wait till the page is loaded.
The way i found in the web is to wait explicitly for a certain element to load.

There is another way in htmlunit, which is to convert all asynchronous javascript to synchronous javascript.

```
 client.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
```

This is more generic, as we don't need to know exactly for which element to wait.
Is there a way to implement this with the firefoxdriver.

Comment: Wait for the specific element to become available, before trying to use it.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you could wait for a specific element that is loaded in the DOM after a Ajax Request.

Suppose you have the following:

```html
<div id="postAjaxRequest">This only appears after something request me!</div>
```

The all you had to do is with a started `WebDriver` and `WebDriverWait` element is the following:

```java
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); // Starts a wait of a maximum 10 seconds.

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("postAjaxRequest")));
driver.findElement(By.id("postAjaxRequest")).click(); // or any other action
```

This is the simplest i could explain.